# Predefined styles won't change

Tags: css, angular, input, angular2-forms

This might be a dumb question:

I'm working on my first ever Angular2, version 7 (school project) SPA and I'm using the Material Angular framework. The framework demands that I use one of their predefined style sheets. I am but I want to change the padding on the matInput tag. Since it generates a lot that isn't shown in the code but you can see it in the inspect view, I think that my selectors in css might not be working?

This is what I've added:

```css
.mat-form-field-wrapper,
.mat-form-field-infix,
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

because in the inspect view, I've been fooling around with the different generated elements and I have been able to pinpoint te location of what I need to change but I just won't do it (again because I think that the matInput generates a lot of code that I can't target whilst writing maybe?). I basically need to change the padding of the .mat-form-field-wrapper.

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Can you try adding the styles to your global stylesheet? are you using angular cli?
https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
/deep/.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I've seen that /deep/ before but I was wondering what it does?

Comment: It is used to allow styling child components when using emulated view encapsulation. 
More about this can be found here:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles
@MoutPessemier

Comment: Use this only as a last resort. it will be deprecated very soon.

Comment: @alt255 How would you solve it then, because I've indeed read that it will be depreciated soon but it works atm.

Comment: Alternative:
You can write your code in styles.css or main.css without deep.
Did my answer fix your problem? @MoutPessemier

Comment: ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
  padding: 0 !important;
}